# I feel like the way I am working with REST and JSON is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I am writing a GET REST API that returns JSON to its client.

In the browser if I wanna take a look at it, my URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/population_management/show.json?id=1
```

Just like a code smell I have the feeling that it isn't the right way of doing it, but I don't know why. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Also in my routes.rb this is what how I have defined this route:

```
get "population_management/show"
```

Comment: The URL should probably be something like http://localhost:3000/population_management/1.json which is what the rails default is.

Comment: thanks Sir., so the way I currently have it is "wrong design" or is it acceptable? or ?

Comment: It's not "wrong" it's just not the standard rails way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to follow REST at a basic level, you probably want to `resources|resource` your routes vs. explicitely defining them (just easier this way, since it does the work of building your routes). You can omit the the actions you don't need with the `:except` or `:only` option.

Or this way is fine as well. (Assuming you want to look up records)

```
match "population_management/:id" => "controller#show", :via => :get
```

[Rails Routes Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)